# What's the cheapest SIM card with Internet for smartphone in Czech Republic?

Tags: cellphones, internet, czech-republic

I want to go to Prague for a few days and do there some geocaching. I need therefore SIM card with internet package or internet flat rate. I don't think the traffic generated while geocaching will be more that 50MB a day, so 200-300MB package instead of flat rate would be also reasonable.

So I want to use only internet, only for a few days, I want to pay as little as possible and the SIM card should be relatively easy to purchase (on train station, for example).

What's the SIM card that fulfills my criteria at best?

Comment: I used a prepaid Vodafon that was bought at the airport. It worked well, more or less (sometimes, money disappeared without me making any call). However, after leaving CZ for several months, when coming back my sim was cancelled, The several hundred crowns on it were- lets say, taken away by Vodafon.
So judge for yourself if you like this attitude.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aha, a site that @Ankur only just showed me earlier this week comes in handy in answering!

The [Pay as You Go Sim with Data Wiki's page on the Czech Republic](http://prepaidwithdata.wikia.com/wiki/Czech_Republic) would appear to answer your question.

You have three main choices - O2, Vodafone and TMobile.

It appears... that O2 might be the best option, as it *looks* like their acceptable use policy is that once you've used the small amount of data a day, the speed throttles down.  Best to confirm this when you buy, of course.  If all you're using it for is a little geocaching, you may not need much data and this could work?

(as an aside, why do you need data to geocache? If you have predownloaded maps (eg Navdroyd app on Android), then all you need is GPS reception, which doesn't use data...)

However, obviously it'll depend on what else you want it for, for how long, and what speeds, so I suggest having a look at the page and seeing what suits best.

Comment: I'm using Locus, the problem is with GeoCaching.com the caches can't be exported to GPX (at least I don't know about it) and must be downloaded on-place based on GPS location. Second, the images are not downloaded both with Locus addon and OpenCaching export, they are downloaded when you open cache description.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. I have friends who cache, but I've never gotten into it yet.

Comment: As a local O2 user, I can confirm this: once you go over the data limit, you'll be throttled to GPRS speeds (some 8 KB/s on average), but you are not cut off from the service. I have used it for exactly this purpose, and while slow, it is still usable.

Answer (score 5):

With the arrival of virtual carriers, the status quo of the Czech mobile market has changed dramatically. Today I would recommend Mobil.cz. Once you activate the $10 SIM, you'll get free 200MB + reasonable FUP and $10 of credit that can be used for calls. The only downside is that if you want more than 200MB without FUP, the only option with Mobil.cz is to buy additional 1GB of data for $15 worth of credit.

Answer (score 3):

When it comes to internet, data sim in Prague, Czech Republic, Vodafone has currently the fastest 3G and 4G in Czech (measured independently by DSL). I recommend to visit the store at the airport at the time of your arrival. They all speak English, and they will find just the right solution for you. Vodafone also has a dedicated website with special plans for VISITORS [here](http://www.vodafone.cz/visitors). You can visit any [store](http://www.vodafone.cz/en/about-vodafone/shops/) and they always have anonymous prepaid cards available. If they don't speak English, just say "Credit SIM". They'll know what you mean.

Comment: Nice to see there's something dedicated for visitors. But the amount of tourists in Prague, for example, is also immense.